# Why didn't Luke require Leia to "give up all worldly attachments" to receive Jedi training

Tags: star-wars, the-book-of-boba-fett

In the Book of Boba Fett: Episode 6, Luke requires Grogu to give up all of his worldly attachments, mainly his attachment to Din Djarin, as a condition of receiving Jedi training. Yet, we know that Luke trained Leia in the ways of the Jedi, and she **did not** have to give up her attachment to Han Solo. She went on to have a child with him "after" receiving her Jedi training. Why didn't Luke make Leia "give up all of her worldly attachments" to receive Jedi training, the same way he did for Grogu, Ben Solo, and every other new student in the New Jedi Temple?

Comment: Probably because she would have said "no". Also, Luke isn't exactly a great teacher. All of his students are dead including the one that went on a murder spree, so maybe he's learned something from that.

Comment: So, essentially, Luke knew that he couldn't impose the same rigid requirements on Leia that he could on his other pupils? Wow! I guess it's "great" to be Leia and it "sucks" to be any other any other student in Luke's New Jedi Order.

Comment: @FrankRendar Is your timescale right, Leia gave up being a Jedi. She may have split with Han during that time and later got back together and had Ben.

Comment: @FrankRendar - Well, sure, that and the whole 'being brutally murdered' bit.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Considering that Ben Solo was born in 5 ABY, I would say that the scene in The Rise of Skywalker where Luke trains Leia, takes place sometime before Ben Solo is even conceived. Whereas, The Book of Boba Fett: Episode 6, takes place in 9 ABY. Obviously, Leia was not held to the same rigid training standards that Luke held his later pupils to.